# Right Hilbert space for a duality pairing

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $B$ be a Banach space. Let $B^*$ be its dual, and let $K\subseteq B^*$ be some linear dense subspace. Denote the duality pairing between $B$ and $B^*$ via $\langle\cdot ,\cdot \rangle$. Suppose we are given a symmetric and linear map $f:K\otimes K \rightarrow B^*$. Does there exists an Hilbert space $H$ with inner product $[\cdot, \cdot]_H$ and a linear and bounded map $g:B^*\rightarrow H$ such that

$$[ga_1,ga_2]_H =\langle f(a_1 \otimes a_2),x \rangle \; \; \; \; \; \forall a_1,a_2 \in K \; \; \; \; x\in B $$

This kind of question led me to thinking about the reproducing Kernel Hilbert space. But maybe this way could not be correct.

Comment: What is $x$ here? Could you provide more background about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think now the question is complete.. But let me add my reasoning..

Comment: By the Moore-Aranszjan theorem, I get that whenever $F:K\otimes K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a positive definite and symmetric operator on $K$ then there is a unique Hilbert space $H$ of functions on $K$ for which $F$ is a reproducing kernel, i.e. there exists $\phi :K \rightarrow H$, s.t.

$$F(x,x')=\langle \phi(x),\phi(x')\rangle_H \; \; \; \;  \; \forall x,x' \in K.$$


Now if I want to use that theorem in the setting of the question I have to fix $x\in B$:
$$F_x(a_1,a_2) = \langle f(a_1\otimes a_2),x\rangle$$
but then the Hilbert space will depend on $x$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to allow to depend on $x$. Something will have to depend on $x$ because otherwise you get that $\langle f(a_1 \otimes a_2), \lambda x \rangle$ is constant in $\lambda$ for some non-zero $x$ and it will follow that $f$ is the zero map. Is it just $g$ that should depend on $x$?

Comment: In the construction of the Hilbert space, see e.g. the very Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space, you can see that the Hilbert space H  is built as the completion of the linear span of $\lbrace F(x,\cdot), \; x\in K$. So actually since our $F(a_1,a_2)=\langle f(a_1\otimes a_2),x \rangle-$ the Hilbert space formed is depending on $x\in B$. That should be the problem in my opinion.

Comment: Sure, when you build a reproducing kernel space via this method it depends on $x$. You've said that you don't want that. But it is unclear to me what you do want. My last comment shows that if you want $g$ to also be independent of $x$ then you can't get anywhere unless you're in the trivial case. You should clarify what your goal is. (also if you don't type e.g. @rhyssteele in your comment i don't get a notification for your reply. Only you get one automatically as it is your question)

Comment: @rhyssteele what I'm searching for is actually a reproducing kernel Hilbert space theory for which one can define a Hilbert space not depending on $x\in B$ but allowing the function g in the statement of the question to be dependent on $x\in B$. The usual RKHS theory comes out with a Hilbert space dependent on $x$, that's the main point.